# Why does 1+ +"2"+3 evaluate to 6 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why and how the expression `1+ +"2"+3` in JavaScript results in `6` and that too is a number? I don't understand how introducing a single space in between the two `+` operators converts the string to a number.

Comment: It doesn't result 5, it results 6. See [Unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) at MDN.

Comment: How is that a `5`, i got `6`! Btw, that `+` will evaluate the string to `Number`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `+"2"` casts the string value (`"2"`) to a number, therefore the exrpession evaluates to `6` because it essentially evaluates to `1 + (+"2") + 3` which in turn evaluates to `1 + 2 + 3`.

```js
console.log(1 + +"2" + 3);
console.log(typeof "2");
console.log(typeof(+"2"));
```

If you do not space the two `+` symbols apart, they are parsed as the `++` (increment value) operator.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple first it convert the string +"2" to number(According to the operator precedence) and then add all these.

For Operator precedence [mozilla developer link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 1):

- `1+ +"2"+3` results 6
- `1+"2"+3` results "123"

The unary `+` operator converts its operand to the `Number` type.

Answer (score 0):

`+"2"` is a way to cast the string `"2"` to the number `2`. The remain is a simple addition.

The space between the two `+` operators is needed to avoid the confusion with the (pre/post)-increment operator `++`.

Note that the cast is done before the addition because the unary operator `+` has a priority greater than the addition operator. See this table: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table